# Set home or working directory

Tags: java

I have a java application and have bundled it as `App.jar`. There are some third party tools I have used (lets call it `NumberGenerator`). `App.jar` starts a process and calls `NumberGenerator` to get the output. To refer the executable, I have used relative paths `new File("lib/NumberGenerator.exe")` and it works all well.

Now on Mac, i have bundled the application using [this](http://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html) and it automatically generates an application launcher. When I run by clicking at launcher, it launches the application. But it sets the home directory as `~` i.e. `/Users/Jatin` and not where the jar file was lying. Hence my application is unable to detect the `lib` folder (Obviously because it doesn't lie in that location)

In my Java code, how do I set the home folder as where my `jar` was lying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

just check this thread [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with linux. I don't know much about osx not AppBundler but in linux I solved it by creating this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
java -Duser.dir=$(pwd) -jar myapp.jar
```

It may work if you manage to run the script by double clicking on it... see [How to run a shell script in OS X by double-clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking)

Comment: Double click doesn't work as the permission has to be set. And I dont want client to open terminal and setup the permission exclusively

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches:

- In `Info.plist`, specify a `java.library.path` relative to `$JAVAROOT`, as described in the articles cite [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

  ```
  <key>Java</key>
  <dict>
  ...    
      <key>Properties</key>
      <dict>
          <key>java.library.path</key>
          <string>$JAVAROOT/</string>
      </dict>
  ...    
  </dict>
  ```
- Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), which lets you manage native [resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) by OS and architecture.

Comment: Nothing special happens when i specify it

Comment: The link to my info.plist https://www.stypi.com/purijatin/nehil.html (default one).

Comment: You can access the `java.library.path` property from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
System.setProperty("user.home", "your-dir");
```

Comment: I do not know `your-dir`. It is an application that needs to be given to client. i do now know it pre-hand. He can launch the application from anywhere

Comment: It can be any location where you want the home directory to be.

Comment: I'm not sure if a relative path can be used. You'll have to figure that out.