# Default file ending in Mac, Linux and Windows to run executable in the shell/terminal

Tags: linux, shell, executable, pyinstaller

I created executables of a python script (via pyinstaller) for Mac, Windows and Linux. For Linux and Mac, I am running them in the shell since it doesn't have an own interface: just open a shell and type the name of the program.

I am wondering if there is a way to use certain file ending so if the user clicks on the program, it will be automatically executed in the shell or terminal. Alternatively, I would appreciate any other ideas of how to do this.

Comment: On linux/mac it's not as much about the extension as it is the execute bit. Is your execute bit set?  What happens when you double-click it?

Comment: Setting the execute bit is only a necessary condition.  How OS's associate a particular file with a particular application (when you click on it in a desktop GUI like the OS X Finder) can be very complicated.  For example: http://arstechnica.com/staff/2009/09/metadata-madness/

Comment: When i double click it, an open-with window pops up. On mac i can choose to open it in a shell, but not in linux. In linux i can only invoke it from within a shell by typing its name

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is not to append a certain file ending, but, as pointed out in the comment, make the file executable (`chmod +x <file>`) and add the magic bytes to the beginning of the file that tell the system how to execute it.

The magic bytes are `#!` and are followed by the path to executable. So for a python script you would put something like the following at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was more looking to a solution that will open and execute an executable in the shell when clicking on it in the file browser. What i basically want to achieve is making a program compiled via pyinstaller from a pyhon script more user friendly

Comment: Basically it should ideally work like an exe file on windows; the exe file i created with pyinstaller for windows automatically opens in the terminal

Comment: You could try changing the command line to `#!/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` or something like that, but that would only work for shell scripts and not be very portable.

Comment: Would it be possible to compile the script into an .app file for MacOS that runs in the shell?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking) may be helpful for that.

Comment: Thank you, Lars, Platypus is a great program to create .app files for MacOS. But now I running into the problem that my program requires the user to make some entries (via raw_input()), the problem is, that the .app does not run in the shell, but for itself. Thus, I get a EOF error when it reaches the raw_input() line.

Comment: That's probably a different question to ask. I don't know anything about Platypus.

Comment: I asked in the other post, I saw that the developer posted an comment there and maybe he will take a look at it. However, the question remains: What about Linux? But I start to think that such a solution does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I finally found out the solution to my question. All you have to do to execute the program upon clicking on it in the file browser is to add the ending `.command` and make it executable

E.g., `exampleprogram.command`. Clicking on it will execute the program in the shell

Comment: I just figured out that this only works for MacOS X, not for Ubuntu, unfortunately