# Mac execute bash script

Tags: macos, execute

I'm on a Mac, and have a bash script that works very nicely.
I'd like to make it so that a double-click will run it, but I don't know the "open with" operand. Please, what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome .. You could put your Mac related question on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a shell script in OS X by double-clicking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking)

Comment: after making it an executable run
./your_bash_file

Answer (score 41):

You'll need to make the file an executable. 
On the first line, before any of your code put in a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

Next, you'll need to change the permissions. On the terminal run:

```
chmod +x your_bash_file
```

Finally, you will need to make sure OS X opens the file using the Terminal and not the application that created the file e.g. your favourite text editor. You can accomplish this in 1 of two ways:

- Save the file with no file extension (eg. `bash_file`, instead of `bash_file.sh`)
- Or, choose `File -> Get Info` and set `Open with:` to `Terminal.app`

You should now be able to click on the script to execute it!

Comment: I would probably use `chmod u+x your_bash_file`. There's no point giving `group` and `other` execute permission if it is not required