# Make a ruby script with text IO double clickable executable file?

Tags: ruby, terminal, executable, desktop

I'm a beginner at Ruby and I don't know how to do this....

Right now I have the script and it runs perfectly in terminal but I was hoping to be able to create a double clickable version of it on the desktop that would then open a window in terminal and run the script. Automator and Platypus don't work. I'm not sure what to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're targeting Mac OS X (Unix) or Linux you can put this line at the top of your Ruby file to make it compatible with the Terminal:

```
#!/bin/ruby
```

Basically, this tells the shell (Terminal) to run the contents of the file with whatever executable you write after `#!`. In this case, you're instructing it to use the `ruby` executable that you use to run your code elsewhere.

To allow the Ruby script to be executed, you'll need to make it executable by running:

```
chmod a+x my_script.rb
```

Finally, to get double clicking support, you might have to replace the `.rb` extension with `.sh` so the operating system recognizes it as a shell script and not a Ruby file.

You might also consider a GUI of some sort. [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) is a great way to create nice user interfaces, and it's really easy to use. It also allows you to generate executable files for Windows, OS X, and Linux if I remember correctly.

Here's an example, which creates a basic, clickable button:

```
Shoes.app do
  @button = button "Click Me"

  @button.click do
    puts "Clicked!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can write a quick shell script that's basically running your ruby script and make this shell script executable. See the link bellow:

[How to run a shell script in OS X by double-clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking)

The content of your shell script can be as simple as that:

```
ruby /yourpath/yourscript.rb
```