# Ruby - Interactive Buttons in Command Line Window

Tags: ruby, user-interface, command-line

I'm not sure if this is possible and, chances are, it isn't but is there any way to have a clickable button in a ruby command line?

I mean, if you run a ruby script in the Ruby command line, can you have an area of the window be clickable and have something executed when it's clicked?

I've been looking around for answers but so far, only Ruby on Rails and website solutions have come up.

Thanks in advance for any help and answers.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445664/make-a-ruby-script-with-text-io-double-clickable-executable-file

Answer (score 0):

I think most people who desire this functionality via terminal end up utilizing the [ncurses library](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). check this Gem out for using ncurses with Ruby: https://github.com/ruby/curses