# Run a Python script from a .command file with Spotlight on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run a Python script from 'Automate the Boring Stuff' on MacOS by opening a .command file with Spotlight. I have been able to successfully run the script in Terminal by navigating to the directory containing the .py file and then entering: `python3 mclip.py [keyword]` , but when trying to run it with my mclip.command file, terminal opens a new window [and displays this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5ael.png)

I'm not sure why it says no such file or directory, because that file definitely exists in said directory. Additionally, even if mclip.command did run successfully, how would I pass to it the [keyword] argument?

The contents of my mclip.command file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 /path/to/my/pythonScript.py
```

and i'm attempting to run it by opening spotlight and typing in 'mclip.command'.

How can I make this work so that I don't have to navigate to the folder containing the .py file every time I want to run the script?

If you want more context, here are some links to the instructions I've been following: First is the instructions for the script itself is under [Project: Multi-Clipboard Automatic Messages](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter6/), and the instructions for creating and running the .command file are under [Running Python Programs on MacOS](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created your `mclip.command` file:

- Go to the `Terminal` and type `cd /your/folder/location/where/command/file/located/`. This changes the current directory where the your command file is located.
- Then type `chmod u+x mclip.command`. This will make your file executable.

Now you should be able to run your script on `Spotlight`. Either:

- Press `Cmd + space` on your keyboard or clic on the magnifying glass on the upper-right corner.
- type `mclip.command` (or just mclip and Spotlight will do the rest) and press enter.

---

I still have a problem though:

- I am **unable to pass arguments** to my command file on `Spotlight`.

I would like to do something like, Go to `Spotlight` and type:

- First `mclip.command save <keyword>` in order to **save** what is copied in the clipboard to the  key.
- Then `mclip.command <keyword>` in order to **reuse** what has previously been saved.

It seems to be very easy to do it on Windows (press `Win-R` and type `mcb save <keyword>`) but somehow it does not seem possible on Mac OS.

Or is it?
I'd love to find a solution or at least a workaround to **quickly execute scripts passing arguments directly on Spotlight**...

Let us know if you have the answer =)

Comment: I found a decent workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854358/mac-osx-allow-for-user-input-in-shell-script-via-gui-or-prompt) from scottgwald.
Basically you can edit the .command file and use the `read` command to accept user input and then pass that as an argument when you tell the .command file to run the code.