# Run a script by double clicking on it in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have a script that I'd like to run.

I know I can open a terminal and run the command:

```
open -na /Applications/Skype2.app \ 
    --args -DataPath /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/Skype2
```

But how can I run it by double clicking on the script, similar to an `app` or `exe` file in windows?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is use the Automator app to create an "Application" containing a Run Shell Script action.

If thats too GUI for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126052/153099