# Programmatically Upload Roku Channel without Eclipse Plugin

Tags: roku

I was wondering if it was possible to upload the zip file of a channel to a roku device using a terminal. It seems like it should be possible because there is a plugin available for Eclipse, but my goal is to not use Eclipse if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a terminal if your machine and the Roku are on the same wireless network.

1. Enable Developer mode on your Roku, press: Home 3 times, Up 2, Right, Left, Right, Left, Right. That will bring up a developers screen where you can see your IP address and can set a password.
2. In your ENV path (.bash_profile or whatever), create a ROKU_DEV_TARGET and USERPASS variable. Set the IP address of the Roku to the ROKU_DEV_TARGET and the password to USERPASS. make sure you reload your terminal window so these env variables are available. Test by typing `ECHO $ROKU_DEV_TARGET` and you should see your IP address there.
3. Next, you need a makefile. You can use the one provided by Roku. Download the [Roku SDK](http://wwwimg.roku.com/static/sdk/RokuSDK.zip) and check out the examples/source/app.mk. You can see it uses the variables we've set above.
4. Copy the app.mk file into your repo, then browse to that directory in your Terminal. run `make install` and it should be able to install to your roku.

NOTE: You may have to mess with the DISTREL, COMMONREL, SOURCEREL paths in the app.mk depending on the setup of your repo.

Helpful hint: in another terminal window, type `telnet $ROKU_DEV_TARGET 8085` to see the console logging from the roku.

Good luck!

Comment: Seems like these days you have to use `DEVPASSWORD` in your environment to store the password. Check the `app.mk` script to confirm.

Answer (score 6):

Why, yes - build & deploy to Roku device is quick and easy, so even a makefile feels like overdoing it. Here is a script i was using for Mac OSX:

```
#!/bin/bash
#ROKU_DEV_TARGET=192.168.1.25   # Roku 2XS
ROKU_DEV_TARGET=192.168.1.28   # put YOUR roku IP here

# wake up/interrupt Roku - workaround for fw5.4 crash
curl -sS -d '' http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET:8060/keypress/Home
curl -sS -d '' http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET:8060/keypress/Home

# build. zip _must_ change for Roku to accept re-deploy (grr!)
cd -- "$(dirname "$0")"
touch timestamp
zip -FS -9 -r bundle * -x run extras

# deploy
curl -f -sS --user rokudev:nuisance --anyauth -F "mysubmit=Install" -F "archive=@bundle.zip" -F "passwd=" http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET/plugin_install  \
| python -c 'import sys, re; print "\n".join(re.findall("<font color=\"red\">(.*?)</font>", sys.stdin.read(), re.DOTALL))'
```

I'd store it as a script file named `run` (marked as executable with `chmod +x run`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710607/226086 for more, like "why not .sh", which was my initial inclination), so that can start it with double-click from Finder too. Or from TextWrangler with cmd-R, as was my case.

PS. i was not even copying the same `run` file to every project but linking to it - but i forgot if it was soft-link or hard-link that worked with a newer TextWrangler.

Comment: if you get 401 error should replace "nuisance" with your own password

Answer (score -2):

Roku might have changed authorization and uses Digest Auth now.
You need to pass various authorization headers for it work successfully.
You need to add `Digest Username`, `Realm`, `nounce`, `uri`, `qop`, `nc`, `cnounce` and `response`.

Script to upload a zip file to Roku -

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization:Digest username="...", realm="...", nonce="...", uri="/plugin_install", qop=auth, nc=, cnonce="", response="..."' --form archive=@example.zip --form "mysubmit=Install" "http://IP/plugin_install"
```