# Using bash to run python script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have a python script that takes in a .txt file and outputs a .txt file. I want to create a bash file that I can click on from my desktop to execute the python script.

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Desktop; 
cd ./py-data;
python ./grab.py;
exit;
```

This just opens up the python script. Ideally I would like to click on the bash script and have the python script to run in the back ground and just produce the output without having to open the python script.

Solution:

1. change py.bat to py.command
2. at terminal:

   `$ cd ~/Desktop
   $ chmod 755 py.command`
3. open code on vim and place in (from: [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)):

   `:set fileformat=unix`
4. Changed code too:

   `#!bin/bash
   cd ~/Desktop
   python search.py
   exit;`

Comment: And if you run the script from the command line-terminal?

Comment: I want it to be a file that is clickable from the desktop so others who do not understand programming can run the python script

Comment: could you edit your question and include the file permissions on your bash script `ls -l`

Comment: The actual solution to this will depend on your operating system. For Linux, you can create a `.desktop` file with your script as the target. Or you may make the script executable (`chmod +x filename)` and set your file manager to execute the files of selected type on clicking

Comment: When you say "opens up the script", do you mean it opens an editable window with the contents of the script? Check to see what your `python` command actually is, because the behavior you describe would be unexpected, to say the least.

Comment: I am developing on OS but would like it to work for PC as well.

Comment: @chepner It opens the editable file pull up script editor

Comment: AFAIK, there is no cross platform solution to this. You will need to handle each platform separately. Plus most PCs don't have bash.

Comment: Yes I will create an executable file for PC

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking

Comment: @pbuck thanks that got somewhere but it is still not producing my output text. Do you know of another solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MacOS, set the name of your script file to end in `.command`, and make the file executable. With that filename extension, you can double-click the file, and it will run `Terminal` application and any output (to stdout / stderr) will be displayed in the terminal window which  pops up for execution.

```
=== /Users/john/Desktop/foo.command ===
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello'
```

Then:

```
===  At command prompt===
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ chmod 755 foo.command
```

Double click on `foo.command` and you'll see window popup:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 5
/Users/john/Desktop/foo.command ; exit;
iMac:~/Desktop john$ /Users/john/Desktop/foo.command ; exit;
hello
logout
[Process completed]
```

In the popup window, you'll see lots of lines, plus your output ("hello").

In your particular example, I think you have two problems:

First, you mention `/Desktop`, which probably isn't what you want, as the user's Desktop is `~/Desktop`. This would cause your script to fail.

Second, the output you would see in the popup window is the output your script writes directly to standard out. If you script is writing to another file, it may be working great, but you'll not see **that** information displayed in the popup (it will be in whatever file you wrote it to.) So it depends what your `grab.py` file actually does.

Finally, you say "run in the background". Technically, that's not what's happening, as it will run in a separate foreground process. I assume that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. That works perfectly.

Comment: Needed to also put in this command: :set fileformat=unix. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You could try `chmod 777` on your bash script and then removing the extension. If you are on macOS then it should work. Not so sure about Linux, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x *filename*
```

Execute the above command in the terminal then make the bash file as follows

```
cd Desktop/*folder*/
python3 *filename.py*
```